# how to overlay one bitmap to another and save on sdcard

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

i am developing image editor and im using custom class to draw bitmap, here is my code..

```
private void settingBitmapToDraw() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    resultBitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resultBitmap, WIDTH, HEIGHT, true);
    Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
    matrix.setRotate(TO_DEGREE);
    tempBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(resultBitmap, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 
    matrix,  true);

    bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT, tempBitmap.getConfig());
    canvas=new Canvas(bitmap);

    invalidate();

}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawBitmap(tempBitmap, xAxis, yAxis, paint);

    if(overlayBitmap!=null)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(overlayBitmap, xAxis+50, yAxis+50, paint);
    }
}

public void overlayImage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ImageProcessing.SAVE_STATUS=false;
    overlayBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.add_image);
    invalidate();

}
```

The bitmap is drawn on canvas but while saving it saves as a black image.
this is my save bitmap code...

```
    try {
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
updatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
    SAVE_STATUS=true;
saveDialog.dismiss();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

updated bitmap is initialized by 'bitmap'

```
public Bitmap getUpdatedImage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //width=2048 height=1232

    Bitmap updatedBitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 
            orgWidth, orgHeight, true);
    return updatedBitmap;

}
```

//////////////
my ImageProcessing.java class has code...

```
if(!SAVE_STATUS)
{
updatedBitmap=ip_DrawingClass.getUpdatedImage();
if(updatedBitmap!=null)
{
    file=new File(file_root);
    saveDialog.show();
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(ImageProcessing.this,
            "file can't saved...",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

and saveDialog has save button which holds code for saving image written above.

///////////////////////////

---

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    float xAxis,yAxis;

    switch(event.getAction()&MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        MODE="DRAG";
        startX=event.getX();
        startY=event.getY();
        if(ImageProcessing.drawLineStatus)
            path.moveTo(startX, startY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        MODE="ZOOM";
        oldDist=this.findDistanceXY(event);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if(MODE=="ZOOM")
        {
            newDist=findDistanceXY(event);
            if(newDist>oldDist)
            {
                this.applyZooming("plus");
            }
            else
            {
                this.applyZooming("minus");
            }
            oldDist=newDist;
        }
        else if(MODE=="DRAG")
        {
            xAxis=event.getX();
            yAxis=event.getY();
            if(!lock_status)
            {
                this.translateImage(xAxis,yAxis,startX,startY);
            }
            else
            {
               this.translateTextOnBitmap
                                         (xAxis,yAxis,startX,startY);
            }

            if(ImageProcessing.drawLineStatus)
            {
                path.lineTo(xAxis, yAxis);
                this.drawLinesOnBitmap();
            }
            else
                draw_line=false;
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        MODE="DRAG";
        this.setZoomBoxXY();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        this.set_XY_Axis();
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

image translate here..

```
 public void translateImage(float x, float y, float startX, float startY) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if((startX>=imageAtX&&startX<=(imageAtX+imageW))&&
                (startY>=imageAtY&&startY<=(imageAtY+imageH)))
    {
        if(imagePortionSelected||crop_status)
        {
            if((startX>=selectorAtX&&startX<=(selectorAtX+ZOOM))
                               &&(startY>=selectorAtY&&startY<=(selectorAtY+ZOOM)))
            {
                left=(int)(x-(startX-selectorAtX));
                top=(int)(y-(startY-selectorAtY));
                right=left+ZOOM;
                bottom=top+ZOOM;
                checkForValidityOfPara();
            }
            rect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
        }
        else
        {
            xAxis=x-(startX-imageAtX);
            yAxis=y-(startY-imageAtY); 
        }
    }

    invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Also share "saving bitmap" code here.

Comment: thanks for ur reply.. i have added my save bitmap code plz see that..

Answer (score 2):

For combining 2  bitmaps use below method

```
public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap frame, Bitmap image) {

    Bitmap cs = null;
    Bitmap rs = null;

    rs = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(frame, image.getWidth(),
            image.getHeight(), true);

    cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(rs.getWidth(), rs.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);

    comboImage.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);
    comboImage.drawBitmap(rs, 0, 0, null);

    if (rs != null) {
        rs.recycle();
        rs = null;
    }
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

    return cs;
}
```

And for saving combined Image use below code wherever you want...

```
 Bitmap outBmp = combineImages(bmp1, bmp2);

    imageFileFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "FOLDER_PHOTOS");
    imageFileFolder.mkdir();
    FileOutputStream out1 = null;

    imageFileName = new File(imageFileFolder, "file_name.jpg");

        out1 = new FileOutputStream(imageFileName);
        outBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out1);
        out1.flush();
        out1.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. you have to save your drawing layout as the image. hope below code will help you.

```
Bitmap bm;
    DrawingLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    bm = DrawingLayout.getDrawingCache();

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    //String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/drawn_image";
    String path = getFilesDir() .getAbsolutePath();
    boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
    /*if (!exists) {
        new File(path).mkdirs();
    }*/
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    File file = new File(path, "drawn_image" + ".PNG");
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);            
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();               

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not drawing on the updated bitmap. Draw the first bitmap and the overlay bitmap on the updated one before saving it. Change your *getUpdatedImage()* to this-

```
protected void getUpdatedImage() {

int width = tempBitmap.getWidth();
int height  = tempBitmap.getHeight();
Bitmap updatedBitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 
        width, height, true);
Canvas canvas  = new Canvas(updatedBitmap);

canvas.drawBitmap(tempBitmap, xAxis, yAxis, paint);

if(overlayBitmap!=null)
{
    canvas.drawBitmap(overlayBitmap, xAxis+50, yAxis+50, paint);
}

//now save the updated bitmap
return updatedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: You may be doing something wrong. Can you post more code in the question along with the flow of operations?

Comment: thanks bro...it works but there is another problem, the remaining space of canvas is drawn as black with bitmap file, is there any solution for this..?

Comment: I am glad it works. For the black space problem, check that the height and width of *updatedBitmap* is same as *tempBitmap* and *overlayBitmap*

Comment: no its not same..// at that point i scale the bitmap at its original size, which i reduced when it is first loaded.

Comment: You should create *updateBitmap* with the size of *tempBitmap* or *overlayBitmap* whichever is smaller and then draw on the canvas. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: yes...but the image is saved small than original. how i get the image with original size and save.

Comment: how to load image with original size...when im trying nothing to be shown on canvas..so i were used insamplesize to 7

Comment: how to draw on large bitmap, bcoz while i translating bitmap and save i is croped and save with same size but with black bg..any help.?

Comment: You can keep track of the boundary of the bitmap inside the black background and then crop and save the image.

Comment: You can probably ask that as  a separate question

Comment: but...my problem is when i translate image on screen it saves image from top-left point to the length of image..plz make sense in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

to save bitmap try this...-

```
 public void savebitmap(final Bitmap bitmap)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Work.this);
alert.setMessage("File name :"); //get file name from user
    input = new EditText(Work.this);
    input.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(100,50));
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String _mNameValue = input.getText().toString();
            try
            {
                File fn=new File("/sdcard/"+_mNameValue+".png");
                FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(fn);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In Save",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90,out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();    
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File is Saved in   "+fn, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();        
            }
        }
    });
    alert.show();
}
```

this is working perfectly at my place.

ontouch event-

```
    paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                    paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Yellow)) ;
                    paint.setAlpha(opacity);

                        _ImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                          _ImageView.setImageBitmap(_MutableImage1);
                          canvas1 = new Canvas(_MutableImage1);
                          canvas1.drawRect(event.getX()-10,event.getY()-10,event.getX()+10,event.getY()+10, paint);
                          bitmap1=_MutableImage1.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444,false);
```

Comment: thanks bro.. i have already done this plz check my updated question..thanks

Comment: for drawing firstly you have to create that original bitmap mutable.so that you can draw on that bitmap.after completion of drawing again make that bitmap immutable like '  _MutableImage2=bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444, true); // for mutable and fro immutable bitmap make it false  bitmapm=_MutableImage2.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444,false);' this will solve your problem

Comment: i have done this..its working at m place.first  do image mutable Bitmap _MutableImage2=orignal_bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444, true); then pass it to draw mathod,after performing operations again make it immutable  bitmapm=_MutableImage2.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444,false) and then save bitmapm

Comment: i already tried this. look at my code, if u find any problem in it, thanks

Comment: i have updated my code.there is sample code of drawing rectangle on image

Comment: make sure that you have addes permisson in manifest file <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: image is saved in sdcard but nothing is shown..i think problem is in my "settingBitmapToDraw()" function or in canvas...see my code if u encounter any problem in it.

Comment: @AlpeshDG u need to go in settings->sdcard & phone storage-> then click on unmount sdcrad and again mount sdcard.then only you will see your image in gallery /sdcard

Comment: bro.. the problem was in sending bitmap, now its solved...but when saving image it also saves dark bg of canvas with it..any solution..?

Comment: if my above code is working please vote my ans.and for saving which code you are using?means the code which i have given is working perfectly

Comment: i mean that, when im saving bitmap the whole canvas is saved so while the dark bg is saved with bitmap.

Comment: for that you need something like crop