# saving bitmap after translation saves bitmap with black area

Tags: android

i have used custom view which contains canvas to draw bitmap, overlay, shapes etc.
this custom view is added to the relative layout in my activity.
my problem is while i translate image on canvas to edit the bottom portion of image, it edits successfully but after editing when i save this bitmap the saved bitmap contains only the part of original bitmap which is shown at a time of save....remaining part of bitmap which is not shown on the screen bcoz of translation is not saved as a black part with bitmap....
any solution to this problem..?
thanks.

```
private void settingBitmapToDraw() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    resultBitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resultBitmap, WIDTH, HEIGHT, true);
    Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
    matrix.setRotate(TO_DEGREE);
    tempBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap
                            (resultBitmap, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, matrix, true);
    if(bitmap!=null)
    {
        bitmap.recycle();
        bitmap=null;
    }   
    bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT, tempBitmap.getConfig());
    canvas=new Canvas(bitmap);
    invalidate();

}
```

Comment: We can't hellp you if we can't see your code. So please edit your question and add your code into it.

Comment: see my code on my question...........                            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757659/how-to-overlay-one-bitmap-to-another-and-save-on-sdcard

Comment: when you save try Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG

Comment: @JRowan it doesn't work

Comment: my prob is not saving bitmap but while saving only the part is saved which is displayed on the scree and remaining part which is not displayed is saved with black area

Comment: are all your bitmaps with Config.ARGB_8888 because saving as black is a transparency thing i think, is it you can see what is on the bitmap just black around it?

Comment: see i added a code to create bitmap